# import image in CSS file from public folder

Tags: reactjs

background-image: url('/images/img-2.jpg');
this is my code and it is still giving me a problem. the image is in public folder I also tried /img-2.jpg but it is still giving me an error. can anyone please answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this
background-image : url("../../../../public/images/urimagename.png);

for best practices use assets/images folder inside the src folder.

something like src/assets/images/allyour_Images.